# accessing setState method from another Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am creating a component `Prompt` that appears on some event.

```js
const Prompt = () => {

    [ visibility, setVisibility ] = React.useState('hidden');

    return (
        <div _visibility={visibility}>
            some contents...
        </div>
    )

}
```

The `Prompt` component may appear when a button is pressed for example, so I could include a button within the prompt that calls `setVisibility`.

```js
const Prompt = () => {
    [ visibility, setVisibility ] = React.useState('hidden');

    return (< >
        <div _visibility={visibility}>
            some contents...
        </div>
        <button 
            onClick={ () => {
                setVisibility( () => "visible" )
            }}
        >
            click to show prompt
        </button>
    </ >)
}
```

However, I want to make this `Prompt` component more general than only appearing on the click of a button.

I want to be able to set the visibility of the prompt from outside of the hook. something like:
(obviously, this example makes no sense)

```js
const Prompt = () => {
    [ visibility, setVisibility ] = React.useState('hidden');

    return (
        <div _visibility={visibility}>
            some contents...
        </div>
    )
}

const ShowPromptButton = () => (< >
    <Prompt />
    <button 
        onClick={ () => {
            Prompt.setVisibility( () => "visibile" )
        }}
    >
        click to show prompt
    </button>
</ >)
```

How can I do this?

edit: `_visibility` is an attribute that changes the style of the `<div>`

Comment: hmm, to keep things simple you can use props, otherwise you can also use state management tools like redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Props drilling** in react.

Change `React.useState('hidden');` to dynamic by replacing 'hidden' with props value for example - `React.useState(props.open);`.

Also while invoking the component have a state(`promptOpen` by default `false`) which can be set to true by updating the state while clicking on the button.

Finally for genericity use `<Prompt open={promptOpen}/>` in all your other component